# Angle condition for $a^2+c^2=nb^2$

Tags: geometry, reference-request, triangles

Find a necessary and sufficient *angle condition* (independent of $a,b,c$ -- see under "what I have got so far" for examples) such that $a^2+c^2=nb^2$ where $n$ is a positive integer.

Note: As usual $BC=a$, $CA=b$, $AB=c$.

What I have got so far:

$a^2+c^2=b^2$ is equivalent to $\angle ABC=90^o$.

$a^2+c^2=2b^2$ is equivalent to $\angle LAC=\angle ABM$ and $\angle ANC = \angle ALB$, where $L,M,N$ are midpoints of the sides $BC,CA,AB$. (Is there a nicer angle condition than this? The "dual" nature of it is slightly unsettling in comparison to the simple "$\angle ABC=90^o$" of the $a^2+c^2=b^2$ case, and the "medians perpendicular" of the $a^2+c^2=5b^2$ case.)

$a^2+c^2=3b^2$. ??? (The answers [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1212942/in-triangle-abc-a2c2-3b2/1212953?noredirect=1#comment2467984_1212953) show that this is equivalent to a length condition in the triangle. How does this length condition convert into a nice angle condition within the triangle, like the ones above?)

$a^2+c^2=4b^2$. ???

$a^2+c^2=5b^2$ is equivalent to the medians $CN$ and $AL$ being perpendicular, where $N$ is the midpoint of $AB$ and $L$ is the midpoint of $BC$.

Comment: Many properties of triangles with $a^2+c^2=2b^2$ are listed in Crux Mathematicorum, v37, n5, "Recurring Crux Configurations".

Comment: I would go for the law of cosines. You have $a^2+b^2=c^2-2ab\cos\gamma$. For your case it becomes $(n-1)c^2=-2ab\cos\gamma$. Therefore $\gamma=\arccos\frac{-(n-1)c^2}{2ab}$ where $c\leq a+b$, to satisfy the triangle inequality. The minus will probably be ok, I guess.

Comment: I think you want an angle condition that is independent of $a,b,c$. You should say so in the question description. Otherwise Kurtovic's comment above answers your question.

Comment: @Kurtovic It's actually $a^2+b^2=c^2+2ab\cos \gamma$.

Comment: @Ark You could use the law of cosines for every of the angles $\alpha, \beta$ and $\gamma$. Write each down, and try to do some math to find some generalization. Thanks for the discussion.